# SFSpeechRecognizer authorization key in Info.plist

Tags: ios10, sfspeechrecognizer

What is key name, that I need to add in `Info.plist` to display speech recognition authorization request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` - for microphone usage authorization.

`NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription` - for asking speech recognition authorization.

Note that speech recognition as any microphone usage is not available in Simulator.

Comment: For me, microphone usage worked in simulator, however speech recognition only worked on a device.